# How do you generate a random decimal with decimals above 0 in Java?

Tags: java, random

I need to generate a random decimal from 0.85 to 1. I saw on other questions a lot of different methods, but all of them count on the beginning number to be 0. How do I do this?

Comment: Well, the general idea is that you only randomise the number you need. So if you need a random number between 0.85 and 1, then what you really need is a randomised number from zero to 0.15, because you can add that to your _fixed_ 0.85 starting value.

Comment: Also you could generate an int between 85 and 100 then divide by 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `Math.random()` will generate a number from 0 to 1, so `Math.random()/100` will generate a number  from 0 to 0.01, so `Math.random()/100*15` will generate a number from 0 to 0.15, so `Math.random()/100*15 + 0.85` will generate a number from 0.85 to 1

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of it:

```
double min = 0.85;
double max = 1.0;
double value = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want numbers between 0.85 and 1, *inclusive*, use [`SplittableRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SplittableRandom.html) and its [`nextDouble(double origin, double bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SplittableRandom.html#nextDouble-double-double-) method, or use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) and its [`nextDouble(double origin, double bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextDouble-double-double-) method.

Since the upper bound is exclusive in those methods, you need to bump up the `double` value by the smallest amount possible, which you can do by calling [`Math.nextUp(double d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-).

```
// Use one of these:
SplittableRandom rnd = new SplittableRandom();

ThreadLocalRandom rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

// Then generate random values like this:
double value = rnd.nextDouble(0.85, Math.nextUp(1d));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of providing an alternative, if `random` has type `Random` then a single double in the range .85 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive) would be:

```
random.doubles(0.85, 1.00).findFirst().getAsDouble();
```

This is more useful if you wish to generate several values within the range.

Note that an advantage of `Random` over `Math.random` is that you can provide a seed which is useful for testing.